# Chrome Extension automatically refreshing options page UI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the options page of my extension, I display the username of the person logged in, along with an option to log out. If they log out, I display instead a link asking them to log in. As well as being able to log in via the options page, they can also do so via the popup.html. The logged-in status is stored in localStorage, which I can access from the options page js.

I would like to be able to listen, in some way, for a change to this status, and update the UI accordingly. If changes are made via the options page, then I of course can change it. However, the issue is if a user logs in whilst via the popup, whilst already on the options page. In that situation, I would still like the options page UI to alter, to now reflect the updated logged-in status. I have thought of 2 different approaches:

(1) Have the background script send a message using chrome.runtime.sendMessage() to the options script every time I change the logged in status.

(2) Add a listener on the localStorage that fires when the logged-in status is changed.

I have tried both approaches, and failed. How can I automatically refresh the UI of my options page depending on the value of a localStorage variable which can be altered from different scripts within the extension?

The answer may be in (1) or (2), however my experience with chrome extensions is limited, so I might have got it programatically wrong and given up too early. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both approaches seem right, so you should show what you have tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer that allows me to send me message between the background and option page scripts. I had previously tried with chrome.runtime.sendMessage, etc..., however must have made a mistake in the way I implemented it.

options.js script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.type) {
        case "loggedin-status-change":
            alert(request.data.myProperty);
        break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

and the background.js script:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    type: "loggedin-status-change",
    data: {
         myProperty: "1"
    }
});
```